# R: Merge two data frames based on value in column and return all values of both data frames

Tags: r, merge

Let's say I have the following dfs

```
df1:
a b c d
1 2 3 4
4 3 3 4
9 7 3 4

df2:
a b c d
1 2 3 4
2 2 3 4
3 2 3 4
```

Now I want to merge both dfs conditional of column "a" to give me the following df

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
4 3 3 4
9 7 3 4
2 2 3 4
3 2 3 4
```

In my dataset i tried using

```
merge <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "a", all = TRUE)
```

However, while df1 has 50,000 entries and df2 has 100,000 entries and there are definately matching values in column a the merged df has over one million entries. I do not understand this. As I understand there should be max. 150,000 entries in the merged df and this is the case when no values in column a are equal between the two dfs.

Comment: Using the example datasets you provided above, the example works. This means it is likely something to do with your datasets' format/structure. What is the output of `str(df1)` and `str(df2)`? One thing to be conscious of is that if the column names are the same in the two datasets it will make new ones by adding `.y` to the columns in the second dataset. I'm assuming this was just for the example though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can do `bind_rows` and `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
     distinct
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 4, 9), b = c(2, 3, 7), c = c(3, 3, 3), 
    d = c(4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c(2, 2, 2), c = c(3, 3, 3), 
    d = c(4, 4, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do is not `merge`but rather `rbind` the two dataframes and remove the `duplicated` rows:

**DATA**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,4,9),
                  b = c(2,3,7),
                  c = c(3,3,3),
                  d = c(4,4,4))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                  b = c(2,2,2),
                  c = c(3,3,3),
                  d = c(4,4,4))
```

**SOLUTION**:

Row-bind `df1`and `df2`:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Remove the duplicate rows:

```
df3 <- df3[!duplicated(df3), ]
```

**RESULT**:

```
df3
  a b c d
1 1 2 3 4
2 4 3 3 4
3 9 7 3 4
5 2 2 3 4
6 3 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible so

```
dplyr::union(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another base R solution using `rbind` + `%in%`

```
dfout <- rbind(df1,subset(df2,!a %in% df1$a))
```

such that

```
> rbind(df1,subset(df2,!a %in% df1$a))
   a b c d
1  1 2 3 4
2  4 3 3 4
3  9 7 3 4
21 2 2 3 4
31 3 2 3 4
```